# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "cdkStep"

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-cdk

I get this error from karma/jasmin in my spec.ts:

> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "cdkStep"

```
<!-- Step 1 -->
<cdk-step [ERROR ->]#step1="cdkStep">
    <ng-template cdkStepLabel>
        <div class="step-content">
<!-- Step 2 -->
<cdk-step [ERROR ->]#step2="cdkStep">
    <ng-template cdkStepLabel>
        <div class="step-content">
<!-- Step 3 -->
<cdk-step [ERROR ->]#step3="cdkStep">
    <ng-template cdkStepLabel>
        <div class="step-content">
<!-- Step 4 -->
```

And I have this declared in my component:

```
@ViewChild('step1') private step1: CdkStep;
@ViewChild('step2') private step2: CdkStep;
```

And this is the TestBed config:

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ StepsComponent ],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
```

Overall, my code is very similar to this Stackblitz example:
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-stepper-demo

I am aware that this question has already been asked multiple times here on SO, *but none of them regarding 'cdkStep'*.
Anyone got an idea what I have been missing? The component works fine - it's just that I can't get a simple `expect(component).toBeTruthy();` get to succeed.

Comment: could you please add your `TestBed` setup?

Comment: Added the  TestBed setup! If I import the CdkStep class, I another error (Unexpected directive 'CdkStep' imported [...])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your component depends on the `cdk-step` component, which would be available in your `TestBed` once you *import* the `CdkStepperModule` into it.

Because this isnt the case, angular does not create an instance of `CdkStep` whenever it encounters the `cdk-step` tag as the association is not registered. Consequentially, you wont be able to bind those template variables to an instance of `CdkStep`, as such instances simply dont exist.

Normally angular would complain whenever it encounters unknown/custom tags by throwing the typical `some-component is not an angular component`, but because you are using the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` this check is skipped.

In order to register the `CdkStep` with the `cdk-step` selector, you need to refactor your setup into:

```
import { CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [CdkStepperModule],
    declarations: [StepsComponent]
}).compileComponents();
```

Comment: Thanks not only for the solution but also for making the effort to explain it so extensively, I understood it now :-)